# How I deserialize the entities in Breezejs in a Shopping cart App

Tags: angularjs, breeze, shopping-cart

I'm developing an Angular Shopping Cart with Breezejs handling the data.

Before saving the transaction I need to authorize with the gateway.

But Breeze doesn't seem to let me do anything before saving, since these are entities.

My question is:

How I deserialize the entities to create the objects for the gateway?

Like so:

```
public SaveResult CheckoutSave(JObject saveBundle)
{
   var billingAddress = saveBundle[0]; //this doesn't work, 
                                       //how to separate the data from the bundle?
   var paymentMethod = saveBundle[1];
   var products = saveBundle[2];

   var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

   // here I'd call the gateway... 
   // and then, I can call the changes...

   return _repository.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
 }
```

Comment: Need a bit more info:  what is _repository?  is it a Entity Framework DbContext or ObjectContext?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy: It is EF object context. I found the solution and I;m about to autoanswer... thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Was pretty easy, as a matter of fact...

I used the delegate:
            _contextProvider.BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate
and extended the function by calling the gateway... the EF handles the transaction if I raise an exception.